# Is there some project/tool for testing web server firewall quality?

Tags: security, firewall

Would like to have a test with different aspects of firewalls. For instance, a test that would output info on:

- Layer 3/4 attacks
- DNS amplification attacks
- SMURF attacks
- ACK attacks
- Layer 7 attacks
- port blocking
  ...

would be items just to name. Is there such a tool that can provide me such a granular feedback if I just input the URL of the web site.
For reference found here different types of the attacks:
https://sucuri.net/website-firewall/ddos-protection
This may be a project like github or so, not necessary online. The thing I haven't found one, doesn't mean there is no one.

Comment: my business problem is how to test the firewall quality from different aspects.

Answer (score 1):

I have never come across an online tool that can do all of this. Usually to ensure these tests are all compliant, you would get an external security audit team in to handle the tests and they would provide you with an idepth report of all vulnerabilities found

There are also a plethora of tools you can use yourself to simulate these type of attack, such as `nmap`, `seige`, `scapy`

Have a look here for more tools http://sectools.org/

Comment: found your answer helpfully, because you provided the concrete tools that would make firewall analysis possible. would be great if there is a project (not necessary online) with exact parameters in to test all the different aspects.